# Delphi - how to get hint from Controls of other Application created from delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a project that will required to grab the hint from controls(e.g. TButton) of another application created from delphi. I used Hook, WH_CBT, using .exe and .dll to make it global and when the mouse point to the control and Hint show and hide, I get the HCBT_CREATEWND and HCBT_DESTROYWND of the hint with it's Handle and SysShadow as class.  But before that, THintWindow is created with its handle, and after that I don't have any idea how to get the text from that hint.  I searched google and no result.

Is there some one who could help me regarding this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I doubt there's a supported way to do this. Perhaps you need to inject into the process. Or maybe use `ReadProcessMemory` and hack it out. Not going to be a lot of fun. If it were me, I'd try to justify giving up!

Comment: Thank you David for the comments and information, i will try using ReadProcessMemory

Comment: Well, it's easy to say, but hard to do. You essentially have to do what a debugger does. Not at all easy.

Comment: It's no different than trying to get controls' 'names' in another application, it's just an internal string field, nothing more. Actually more complicated than names, there's also the case of actions.

Comment: any idea how to get the text?

Comment: @Anthoner - Not really. I think I'd go for the resources. Locate the backing files for running modules, look for resources resembling dfms. Maybe that could identify a hint or two... On second thought, I think I'd give up on that....

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Rading RC_Data in order to extract .dfms and then reading value of Hint property would only work if the hint message is stored in that property. But what if the program uses OnHint events on which you can modify the hint message at runtime. In that case such approach would not work.

Comment: @Silver - You don't have to use OnHint to modify a hint, a hint can be modified anytime at run-time. Anyway I *hinted* this and other possible problems in my comment by *"maybe that could identify a hint or two..."*.

Comment: Not sure when you need to read the hints controls. is it only when the hint window is actually showing or before that? do you have the handle of `THintWindow`?

Comment: If you need to get the Hint text when the Hint is actually activated, then you could create a global `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook and check for `if (GetClassName(Msg.hwnd) = 'THintWindow') and (Msg.message = WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED) then
         GetWindowText(Msg.hwnd)`

Comment: Hi Kobik, this one works fine, thank you

Comment: @Anthoner - Notice that kobik's comment begins with "if you need ..". That's because the question does not give any clue about *when* you want the hint. I, for one, never suspected that you need the hints just when they're activated. In general, try to make your questions as precise as you can.